# How to avoid spinng sharkbite on moen spout?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, shower, tub

What new spout did you get to avoid the sharkbite to moen connection?

Comment: Sorry but we're going to need some more details in order to answer this.  Maybe a picture of the problem?  FYI sharkbites will turn even though they are sealed.

Answer (score 1):

Sharkbites always spin when connected properly.  Well the seal part doesn't but the cover does.  If you don't want it to spin I would use copper.

Comment: Indeed. The spinning is actually one of the benefits of a sharkbite (in many situations)

Comment: @DA01 - Exactly, you just can't use it for spouts or toilet shutoffs and stuff like that.  I have a ghetto (but long-term) way to stop the spin but will keep that to myself.